# Firebird Embedded on web hosting

Tags: asp.net, firebird

i have problems on using firebird embedded on my asp.net web host .

everything work fine locally but on the web i have an exception

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: Can't create directory "C:\ProgramData\firebird\". OS errno is 5 ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: Can't create directory "C:\ProgramData\firebird\". OS errno is 5

what i have done :
- copy fbembed.dll and it's depencies in the Bin Folder
- copy also firebird config file in and change the root variable to absolue Bin path
- copy my database to app_data folder

i also build my connectionstring dynamically like this

```
   string p = "metadata=res://*/MyFBEmbedModel.csdl|res://*/MyFBEmbedModel.ssdl|res://*/MyFBEmbedModel.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string='client library=??fbembed??;initial catalog=|DataDirectory|D2015.gdb;user id=sysdba;password=masterkey;Connection lifetime = 0; Pooling = true; MinPoolSize = 0; MaxPoolSize = 500; Packet Size = 8192; ServerType = 1'";


        string mslinepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Default.aspx");
        mslinepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(mslinepath);
        p = p.Replace("??fbembed??", mslinepath + @"\Bin\fbembed.dll");
        context = new MyFBEntities(p);
```

any help is more than welcome

Comment: ps: i am using this database for readonly access , and instantiating the first entity make this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference error number 5 is access denied. Firebird writes the lock 
files for a database into C:\ProgramData\firebird but it isn't able to 
create the folder (you don't have enough rights).

To redirect the lock files, you need to set the environment variable 
`FIREBIRD_LOCK` to the location where you can write.

See also this discussion: 
http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/FB-Tracker-Created-CORE-3197-Firebird-inet-server-consumes-100-CPU-and-hangs-all-connections-td3013382.html

I also posted this answer on the Firebird-support mailinglist.

Comment: thanks Mark, isn't possible to change the firebird_lock variable in the firebird config files or something like ? (not found that option) and since i am in shared web hosting , setting environment variables is not allowed imo

Comment: I am not sure I'd it is possible to specify this site specific on IIS. I don't know if there is another solution except for asking your hosting company to create the folder and making it read/writable for all (which is a security risk on shared hosting) or they would need to configure it just for you.